# How to keep the results of a search with Postgres

Tags: search

Have a website on which i need to implement searching... The bd (Posgres) is returning (for example) 100 record, but i need to show only 10. Where and how to store the returned results both shown and unshown.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET? Look for ASP.NET pagination and you'll find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with the Postgres syntax, but you can use [`LIMIT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html) to only get the 10 records that you need.

However, you'll have to elaborate more on what you mean by "store the returned results" for me to answer that. Depending on what you need, the programming language you are using might also be important.

Comment: LIMIT doesn't satisfy me because in case i need to see the next 10 results from 100 (need to see the results 11-20) then there must be another call to the DB. I would like to have a way of storing the results and when needed to take them from the storage place
I am using ASP.NET